# Not possible to add a RecyclerView via AndroidStudio in Design mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

is it not possible to add a RecyclerView via AndroidStudio in Design mode?

[image]

Comment: Views from libraries -- `RecyclerView`, `ViewPager`, etc. -- do not appear in the palette at the present time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on the Custom View tab and find the RecyclerView there. You won't find it in the Palette.

[image]

As Haroon pointed you have to add it's dependency in the Gradle first

```
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1"
```

Comment: Only if dependency is added in gradle

Comment: Yeah exactly. RecyclerView isn't a part of default framework so it has to be added as dependency in the gradle. After that you can find it in the CustomView tab ;). Thanks for pointing that Haroon.

Comment: I was going to answer, but you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I image it's because RecyclerView is part of the support library and not the main framework.